# XML Import script error - simplexml_load_string

Tags: xml, xpath, import, simplexml

I have a XML import script which uses "simplexml_load_string" to import a Feed of real estate properties. The script is scheduled to run 1am each night.

It has worked fine for many months; but yesterday it started to error with the below:

```
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]:
Entity: line 2: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in /public_html/import/import-script.php on line 26

PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: &lt;body&gt;&lt;h1&gt;Object Moved&lt;/h1&gt;This object may be found &lt;a HREF=&quot;http://admin.homees in /public_html/import/import-script.php on line 26

PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: ^ in /public_html/import/import-script.php on line 26

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in /public_html/import/import-script.php on line 28
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Content-type: text/html
```

I cannot understand why this error shows; as the feed still opens in a browser all ok. Plus W3C validate it as all ok too.

Please can anyone explain what this error means / why I might be seeing it?

Also I check the Server Log and it says:
[error] [client 46.208.46.63:41713] AH01215: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in /public_html/import/import-script.php on line 30

This is a snippet of our PHP import script:

```
$ch2 = curl_init();
$timeout = 60; 
curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "external-website/provided-feed.xml");
curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$xmlstring = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2); 

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$propertys = $xml->xpath("//property");
$count=0;
```

Huge thanks in advance! Craig.

Comment: Does the var $xmlstring outputs the correct XML after the curl requets ?

Comment: Hi, we have now fixed the issue which was simply setting curl option CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to true. Looks like there was a redirect issue on the feed. Thanks Guys.